# Error 500.30 when publishing WTelegramClient app to Azure

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, telegram-api, wtelegramclient

I've made a web app in .NET 6.0 using WTelegramClient.
It works fine locally but when I try to publish it to Azure App Service i obtain the following error:
HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start

I tried to remove WTelegramClient initialization from app and it works fine on Azure too.

This is my Config function:

```
public static string Config(string what)
        {   
            switch (what)
            {
                case "api_id": return Instance.m_oTgConfig.api_id;
                case "api_hash": return Instance.m_oTgConfig.api_hash;
                case "phone_number": return Instance.m_oTgConfig.phone_number;
                case "verification_code": Console.Write("Code: "); return Console.ReadLine();
                case "first_name": return Instance.m_oTgConfig.first_name;    // if sign-up is required
                case "last_name": return Instance.m_oTgConfig.last_name;        // if sign-up is required
                case "password": return Instance.m_oTgConfig.password;     // if user has enabled 2FA
                case "session_pathname": return "/WTelegram.session";
                default: return null; // let WTelegramClient decide the default config
            }
        }
```

Am I doing somethin wrong with the .session file?

I think that the problem is that I must to insert verification_code (telegram OTP) by hand from the console. In local I do it from the console. How can I do the same thing in Azure? If I run MyApp.exe from Azure's console it do not ask anything.

Comment: In Azure, you need to enable logging in web.config file - through Kudu services - and investigate the stack trace in the log file produced after you try to publish the app. I don't think this question has enough details to give proper solution

Comment: Most likely, your appsettings.json is missing some parameters because of the environment. You could try to start with publishing application in Development configuration to see if it works

Comment: In azure app configuration check if the process is set to 64 bit . Try changing it, then restarting the app

Comment: If I run MyApp.exe from Azure console i obtain: 
Unhandled exception: System.ApplicationException: You must provide a config value for verification_code. How do I insert my verification code from console if it do not ask for it?

Answer (score 0):

See WTelegramClient [ASP.NET example](https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient/raw/master/Examples/ASPnet_webapp.zip) for how to login & prompt for the `verification_code` interactively via a web page.

Make also sure `session_pathname` points inside a directory where you have read/write access so the session file can get saved there.

And before further questions, please read the [ReadMe file](https://wiz0u.github.io/WTelegramClient/) and the [FAQ page](https://wiz0u.github.io/WTelegramClient/FAQ) as they both answer your issue